# Insert multi nested object with lists and other properties to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I create a web service and I have to insert multi nested object to the database. Can I insert all the objects at the same time or should I add each object individually one by one?

It seems it's not optimal way. I implemented Onion Architecture in my solution and I add each object by other service. Is this a correct way? The object which I want to insert is AwsRekognitionResponse. I would like to know which way is the most optimal and correct.

```
public class ResponseMetadata
{
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
    public int RetryAttempts { get; set; }
    public int HTTPStatusCode { get; set; }
}

public class Emotion
{
    public decimal Confidence { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Landmark
{
    public decimal X { get; set; }
    public decimal Y { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class MouthOpen
{
    public decimal Confidence { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}

public class Sunglasses
{
    public decimal Confidence { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}

public class BoundingBox
{
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public decimal Width { get; set; }
    public decimal Top { get; set; }
    public decimal Left { get; set; }
}

public class FaceDetail
{
    public Emotion[] Emotions { get; set; }
    public Landmark[] Landmarks { get; set; }
    public MouthOpen MouthOpen { get; set; }
    public Sunglasses Sunglasses { get; set; }
    public BoundingBox BoundingBox { get; set; }
    public decimal Confidence { get; set; }
}

public class AwsRekognitionResponse
{
    public string OrientationCorrection { get; set; }
    public ResponseMetadata ResponseMetadata { get; set; }
    public List<FaceDetail> FaceDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It depends on your DB provider and frameworks you are using. E.g., With EF you only have to insert the "AwsRekognitionResponse" object and everything is done.